# AWS Amplify Storage: No plugin found in Storage for the provider

Tags: aws-amplify

My AWS Amplify was working perfectly to use Storage during my last app build, and now I receive "No plugin found in Storage for the provider" error. I made no changes to the config. Below are my amplify version:

```sh
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "1.2.14",
    "@aws-amplify/core": "1.0.21",
    "aws-amplify": "1.1.28",
```

I'm kind of confused on which version to upgrade/downgrade without breaking the authentication one.